# how to use runOnUiThread without getting "cannot make a static reference to the non static method" compiler error

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a main class;

```
  ClientPlayer extends Activity {
```

and a service

```
  LotteryServer extends Service implements Runnable {
```

when trying to use the RunOnUiThread in the run method of this service I am getting compiler error of, "cannot make a static reference to the non static method"

how to fix this?,  how I am using the code is shown here;

```
     @Override
public void run() {
   // I tried both ClientPlayer.runOnUiThread and LotteryServer.runOnUiThread
   // both don't work   
    ClientPlayer.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "from inside thread", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
} // end run method
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

runOnUiThread is not a static method.

If u want to run your runnable on  UIThread You can use this

Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

This will create a handler for UI Thread.

```
ClientPlayer extends Activity {
.
.
public static Handler UIHandler;

static 
{
    UIHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
}
public static void runOnUI(Runnable runnable) {
    UIHandler.post(runnable);
}
.
.
.
}
```

Now u can use this anywhere.

```
@Override
public void run() {
   // I tried both ClientPlayer.runOnUiThread and LotteryServer.runOnUiThread
   // both don't work   
    ClientPlayer.runOnUI(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "from inside thread", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
} // end run method
```

Comment: tried this but getting null pointer for context wrapper.   for the Toast I tried every context I can think of and it will not work. and i tired to pass context from the activity class but I can't do that because in a service you can't pass context in the constructor

Comment: You might be getting null pointer exception when the activity/service on which it is called is destroyed or never started so now no context is available to display the toast.

Comment: Make sure your service or activity on which this is called is started.

Answer (score 14):

There is a very simple solution to the above problem
just make a static reference of your Activity before your `onCreat()` method

```
MainActivity mn;
```

then initialize it in you `onCreat()` method like this

```
mn=MainActivity.this;
```

and after that you just have to use it to call your `runOnUiThread`

```
mn.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        tv.setText(fns);///do what
                                    }
                                });
```

hope it work.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the instance of your Activity, pass it to the service, and use that instead of the class name.

then you can use:

```
yourActivity.runOnUiThread( ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally we use this method(RunOnUiThread)  when we try to update our UI from a working thread. but As you are Using Service Here, `runOnMainThread` is seems inappropriate as per your situation.

Better to Use **[Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)** here. Handler is an element associated to the thread where is created, you can post a runnable with your code to the Handler and that runnable will be executed in the thread where the Handler was created.

> Create a Handler on your Service in his MainThread and post Runnables on
>   it / send messages to it.